# Single character in placeholder attribute (in bangla) showing up as �

Tags: html, encoding

I faced problem to use bangla language in HTML placeholder of input area.Here is my code :

```
<textarea name="address" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="যে ঠিকানায় পণ্য যাবে"></textarea>
```

and here what it showing in my web page:

[my page screenshot link.](http://prntscr.com/7lhn8z)

Comment: Is the problem the wrong char in the image? I suggest you to specify it in the question.

Comment: The ` �` represents an "unknown or unrepresentable character". It seems weird that this would show up in a homogenous string with all other characters displayed correctly. Can you delete the entire placeholder, and write it again, to exclude the possibility of copy+paste errors?

Comment: http://www.connect-bangladesh.org/bangla/webbangla.html

Comment: I didn't copy+past it . it's correct in localhost. but when I uploaded it host server , I am facing problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

log-in to your host server . Go to file manager and check placeholder .If it is not same to this one ,then copy it and past it or write there your bangla sentence.

```
placeholder="&#2479;&#2503; &#2464;&#2495;&#2453;&#2494;&#2472;&#2494;&#2527; &#2474;&#2467;&#2509;&#2479; &#2479;&#2494;&#2476;&#2503;"
```

Comment: give me your page link .

Answer (score 0):

HTML doesn't support all characters, therefore you must check which work and which don't.

Comment: Which characters doesn't HTML support?

Comment: not quite sure what characters you have there but check this out: [link](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/guide/entities.html)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you have included `UTF-8` in meta:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

This is more of a browser issue. There will be some browsers which will display it correctly.

If it still happens, you can refer this link to insert the entities.

http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/bylanguage/bengalichart.html